# Automatic Dark/Light Icon Support in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I think this is a very common problem, but I cannot find a suitable solution for me. As you all know, WP supports a dark and a light theme. The user can change the theme and there are ways to override his decision and to display everything in the color theme you've selected. However, I'm just trying to react to this two theme types and I want to display icons in the correct color.

If you use the Application Bar, you can select from many built in icons, which will be automatically inverted from light to dark and vice versa.

Why isn't there any support for normal images? For example: I want to display a telephone icon. I've picked one from the built in icons and copied it from the Microsoft SDK folder to the Image folder of my project. If the user uses the dark theme, everything will be fine because the white telephone icon will be visible on the black background. But if he switches to the light theme, the icon will be invisible because it is white on white.

I'm fully aware of the style resources for textboxes or background colors, which use the phone's accent or theme color. But why is it, that there is no support for simple icons which I added as Image to my XAML page?

Of course I could detect in the constructor of the page if the user is in dark or light mode. I would then load either a black or white version of the telephone icon. But this check will be done everytime I visit the page and slows everything down. It's also annoying to manually add the check for the theme each time I'm adding a theme aware image.

Is there any solution, which will work with XAML only? Or is at least easy to maintain? And why can't I use the built in images from the SDK right from the beginning? They are already available in dark and light versions and are already used in the application bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the icons provided with the WP7 sdk properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919882/how-do-i-use-the-icons-provided-with-the-wp7-sdk-properly)

Comment: Yes I've seen that question too, but I want to avoid the solution using opacityMask and having to define every button state (if I'm using the image as a clickable)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want the icon to function like in the actionbar, just be white (if dark theme) and black (if light theme) then you can add the image as an opacity mask to a rectangle, like this:

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Width="48" Height="48" >
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/my.icon.png" />
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Where my.icon.png is a white image, like those you can choose for the actionbar.

Comment: That's it! Minimal effort and maximal results :) Although I thought the OpacityMask way would be way more complicated it seems to be a perfect fit for the black/white icons only. Could this combination of Rectangle and OpacityMask be used in a single style definition? I would like to create a single style that can be used throughout the application for all icons I use. Another question: What about different color images? Then I would go with Erno's solution, as this is only for black and white images.

Comment: Totally awesome, I've used this Three times now and everytime I have to Google it up again :)

Comment: How about Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)?

Comment: @JohnCroneh: Ye, OpacityMask is not available for Universal Apps, there are a few different ways to achieve the same result depending on your situation and type of image, I found this useful blog post a while ago: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/07/07/Alternatives-to-OpacityMask.aspx that I used when solving this problem for my universal apps.

Answer (score 3):

You could use vector graphics instead of bitmap icons and use a theme-aware brush to draw them.

If you want the App to respond to a switch of the theme you'll need to respond to it any way.

I added a property to the base class of my Views that returns the selected theme. That way I can use/bind to that value.

It is also possible to use a ValueConverter that turns a logical name of a resource into a name of a theme specific resource.

**Edit**

Have a look at this: [Custom light/dark theme resources on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: I don't want to create new graphics, as the built in are sufficient for me. But I've seen instructions on how to create a vector graphic in xaml which could be used. But this is again too much work, especially when the graphics already exist :/ I've tried a converter solution but was not successful. But it seems to be the most practical solution in my eyes. Could you give me an example how you solved this problem in your views?

Comment: I added a very useful link that allows you to put the light and dark resources in seperate resource files and loads them.

Comment: I gave your link a try, but I'm stuck with adding the ThemeResourceDictionary. Either it does not exist in the namespace or "each dictionary entry must have an associated key".

Comment: @MarkusRudel - it is hard to debug that with so little info. It looks to me like you added the the resource dictionaries in the wrong way.

Comment: you're right, but there too little space in the comment box. Maybe I'll ask this in another question.

Answer (score 2):

Detect the theme ([Supporting dark and light themes](http://timdams.com/2011/06/21/creating-a-wp7-app-supporting-dark-and-light-themes/) gives the best solution for this, I think), and then set the image accordingly. If you do this a lot, a custom control where you can supply two image sources and the correct one gets used would be easy enough to create.

**Edit:** Here's another good article on this topic. [New Screen Resolutions](http://vdcruijsen.net/2012/11/8-days-of-windows-phone-8-day-4-new-screen-resolutions/)

Comment: As I've written in my original question: I'm looking for a solution which does not require code which decides what image should be loaded and assigned.

Comment: It's a program. Everything requires code. ;) The code necessary can easily be wrapped up in something reusable by XAML markup. I suggested that.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I wanted to stay as close as possible to original classes and functionality. Sure it is possible to write your own controls which take care of your needs but I was looking for a simple solution like Johan Falk suggested :) I still cannot understand why there is only theme support for text and the application bar icons and not throughout the system.

Answer (score 0):

You pick a White Foregrounded icon use it. It suits for both Light and Dark themes. Thats what I have been doing.

Comment: Hm? If you use a white icon on white background, you will not see anything... There must be at least a light gray background behind the white icon to see anything at all, otherwise the controst will be too low.

Answer (score 0):

The [Coding 4 Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) control toolkit includes a round button that mimics the application bar buttons, including updating the foreground color depending on the theme. The code is open source, so perhaps you might find an answer in there. Or, as a hack, you could use the RoundButton control, turn off the border, and not provide a `Click` event.